# How do I swap weapons?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

How can I change weapons?  I have most of them at the ammunition store but I cannot equip them. I have looked for videos and the game controls but nothing has worked. I have tried changing the tab button so that I can get the wheel up in the gun store but nothing works. How do I swap between weapons (such as pistols and shotguns)?

Comment: ok i just noticed that you can buy a number of guns from your  gun store the wont show up on the gun wheel but wheny ou get into a car you can push tab untill you get the gun you want then when you get out of your car you will have the last one you selected on your gun wheel... ( i dont know if this works with rockets or snipers... it just worked with uzi, pistol, thrown weopons

Answer (score 15):

You can cycle through all of your weapons by tapping tab, or scrolling your mousewheel.

It is also possible to use the number buttons (1,2,3 etc.) to cycle through weapons. If for example, "1" is pistols, you can cycle through all of your pistols by tapping 1 multiple times.

There is one more way, the one I think is the best, to cycle through your weapons, and multiple ones in a category. You just hold down tab, and you get to see the entire weapon wheel. With the mouse you can select any of the weapon categories, and while still holding down tab you can scroll your mousewheel to cycle through guns in that category.

If you're playing singleplayer, the last one will also slow down the game. You'll have plenty of time to select your weapon. The other ones don't affect game speed.

If you buy a new weapon at ammu-nation, it will be added to your weapon wheel. There is no limit on weapons you can carry.